# No permission to access /server-info on this server

Tags: apache-2.2

```
a2enmod info.load
service apache2 restart
```

To input `myvps_ip/server-info' in firefox ,an error info occur:

```
You don't have permission to access /server-info on this server.

cat   /etc/apache2/mods-available/info.conf
<IfModule mod_info.c>
    <Location /server-info>
            SetHandler server-info
            Require local
            #Require ip 192.0.2.0/24
    </Location>
</IfModule>
```

How to set the config file to access servero-info on vps_ip?

Comment: comment out the [`require local`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_authz_host.html#reqlocal)? I wouldn't recommend to leave this accessible on a server that is publicly available though.

Answer (score 0):

You tagged the post apache2.2 which means you would need `allow from` instead of `require`.

Also `require local` would not be valid for either version. You probably want

```
# Apache v2.4
Require ip <your CIDR>
# Apache v2.2
Allow from <your CIDR>
```